# UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification not called iOS 14

Tags: swiftui, ios14

I have a project with a `SceneDelegate` and I am using the following code in a SwiftUI View:

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)) { _ in
    print("Did become active...")
}
```

It is called in iOS 13 but when I run it on iOS 14 it doesn't run.

More details: `didBecomeActiveNotification` is called when I put the app into foreground after having put it into background, but when app is opened for the first time it's not. But in iOS 13 it does on the first open call it.

I updated Xcode from 12.2 to 12.3 and the problem still exists. Could someone check if they get the `didBecomeActiveNotification` called when app is opened using iOS 14?

Any idea how to make this work?

PS. To create a project using SceneDelegate on Xcode 12 the `AppName.app` file should be deleted, then create `SceneDelegate.swift` and `AppDelegate.swift` files with boilerplate code and edit the `info.plist` "Application Scene Manifest" key to make it use SceneDelegate.

Answer (score 4):

I did some tests and it seems you're right. I'm not sure whether it's a bug or an intended change.

The only working solution for me was `onReceive` + `Just` + `scenePhase`:

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase

    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .onReceive(Just(scenePhase)) {
                print("onReceive scenePhase \($0)")
            }
    }
}
```

Other tests below (Xcode 14.3, iOS 12.3):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) private var scenePhase

    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            // not working on the first launch
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)) { _ in
                print("onReceive didBecomeActiveNotification")
            }
            // not working on the first launch
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification)) { _ in
                print("onReceive willEnterForegroundNotification")
            }
            // not working on the first launch
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didFinishLaunchingNotification)) { _ in
                print("onReceive didFinishLaunchingNotification")
            }
            // **working** on the first launch
            .onReceive(Just(scenePhase)) {
                print("onReceive scenePhase \($0)")
            }
            // not working on the first launch
            .onChange(of: scenePhase) {
                print("onChange scenePhase \($0)")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this input, onAppear is always called both in ios13 and 14 on first launch, I am going for a solution where I use both onAppear and becomeActive to execute the needed code

Comment: Doing it `onChange` seem to work on iOS16.  Here is the reference: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/how-to-be-notified-when-your-swiftui-app-moves-to-the-background